# How to Roundup by a certain Round up factor?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

```
If x = 1.71 Then output = 1
If x = 1.82 Then output = 2
```

My round up factor is `0.8`

How do I achieve this in Oracle stored procedure calculations?

Comment: Can you give some more examples; what should 1.80 go to for instance, 1 or 2?

Comment: 1.8 should go to 2. If decimal value is 0.8 or above, the ceiling value would be considered.

Answer (score 2):

From the minimal examples you gave, you want to `ceil()` with an adjusted value:

```
ceil(x - 0.8)
```

Demo with some sample values in a CTE:

```
with t (x) as (
  select 1.5 + (level - 1)/10 from dual connect by level <= 5
  union all select 1.71 from dual
  union all select 1.78 from dual
  union all select 1.79 from dual
  union all select 1.81 from dual
  union all select 1.82 from dual
)
select x, ceil(x - 0.8)
from t
order by x;

         X CEIL(X-0.8)
---------- -----------
       1.5           1
       1.6           1
       1.7           1
      1.71           1
      1.78           1
      1.79           1
       1.8           1
      1.81           2
      1.82           2
       1.9           2
```

It's unclear what should happen with 1.8.

In PL/SQL you can do the same thing:

```
y := ceil(x - 0.8);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ROUND` and an offset from `.5`. So for your factor of `0.8` then `0.5 = 0.8 - 0.3` so round subtracting `0.3` from your values:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/693ce/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
  SELECT +1.71 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT +1.80 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT +1.81 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT -1.19 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT -1.20 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT value,
       ROUND( value - 0.3 ) AS rounded_value
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/693ce/1/0)**:

```
| VALUE | ROUNDED_VALUE |
|-------|---------------|
|  1.71 |             1 |
|   1.8 |             2 |
|  1.81 |             2 |
| -1.19 |            -1 |
|  -1.2 |            -2 |
```

---

Depending on how you want to handle values at the rounding factor boundary then there are different methods using `ROUND`, `FLOOR` and `CEIL` which each give different results at the boundary values:

- `ROUND( value - 0.3 )` will round values at the boundary away from 0 - so will round positive values up and negative values down.
- `CEIL( value - 0.8 )` will round values at the boundary down.
- `FLOOR( value + 0.2 )` will round values at the boundary up.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c88373/1)

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT value,
       ROUND( value - 0.3 ) AS rounded_value,
       CEIL( value - 0.8 ) AS ceiling_value,
       FLOOR( value + 0.2 ) AS floored_value
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c88373/1/0)**:

```
| VALUE | ROUNDED_VALUE | CEILING_VALUE | FLOORED_VALUE |
|-------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|  1.71 |             1 |             1 |             1 |
|   1.8 |             2 |             1 |             2 |
|  1.81 |             2 |             2 |             2 |
| -1.19 |            -1 |            -1 |            -1 |
|  -1.2 |            -2 |            -2 |            -1 |
| -1.21 |            -2 |            -2 |            -2 |
```